# Ideal Data Structure to Deal with XML Data

Tags: python

Maybe a silly question, but I usually learn a lot with those. :)

I'm working on a software that deals a lot with XML, both as input and as output, and in between a lot of processing occurs.

My first thought was to use internally a dict as a internal data structure, and from there, work my way with a process of reading and writing it.

What you guys think? Any better approach, python-wise?

Comment: I think this is a googleable thing, but what types of things are you planing on doing with xml ? Does it need to be fast?  Are you generating it or just reading it?  etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An XML document in general is a tree with *lots* of bells and whistles (attributes vs. child nodes, mixing of text with child nodes, entities, xml declarations, comments, and many more). Handling that should be left to existing, mature libraries - for Python, it's commonly agreed that [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is the most convenient choice, followed by the stdlib [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) modules (by which one lxml module, `lxml.etree`, is so heavily inspired that [incompabilities](http://lxml.de/compatibility.html) are exceptions).

These handle all that complexity and expose it in somewhat handable ways with many convenience methods (lxml's XPath support has saved me lot of code). After parsing, programs can - of course - go on to convert the trees into simpler data structures that fit the data *actually modeled* much better. *What* data structures exactly are possible and sensible depending on what you want to represent (if you misuse XML as a flat key-value storage, for instance, you could indeed go on to convert the tree into a dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

It depends completely on what type of data you have in XML, what kinds of processing you'll need to do with it, what sort of output you'll need to produce from it, etc.